# C # Linq equivalent of SQL nested group by

Tags: c#, linq

I am a beginner in C#. Struggling to write the equivalent of the following SQL in Linq . I have the data of the base table (table_a) loaded in a data table but can't progress further.

```
 select count([Opportunity]) [OCount]
         ,sum([TotalPremium]) [TotalPremium]
  from( Select  concat([ID],[ID2]) [Opportunity]  
                ,max ([PremiumAmount])[TotalPremium]
                from table_a
                where col1='abc'
                 and col2='xyz'
                 and col3='pqr'
                group by concat([ID],[ID2])
       )[Inner]
```

Any help will be beneficial .

Thank you.

Comment: TRANSACT (SQL Server Query) language is limited so you sometimes have to nest SELECT statements.  Linq you have much more flexibility.  Often when I convert TRANSACT to Linq I totally reorganize the query.  So there often is an exact one-to-one mapping when doing a conversion.  Line query you can nest queries by putting a select inside a select like Select(x => x.Select(y => y)).  So a nested group in linq is similar to the nested Select I posted.

Answer (score -2):

```
var Inner = table_a
    .Where(x => x.col1 == "abc" && x.col2 == "xyz" && c.col3 == "prq")
    .GroupBy(x => x.ID + x.ID2)
    .Select(grp => grp.Max(x => x.PremiumAmount));

var OCount = Inner.Count();
var TotalPremium = Inner.Sum();
```

Comment: This solution will run the query twice.

Comment: So it only runs once, you should just be able to move the last two lines into a select statement: 
var result = table_a
    .Where(x => x.col1 == "abc" && x.col2 == "xyz" && c.col3 == "prq")
    .GroupBy(x => x.ID + x.ID2)
    .Select(grp => grp.Max(x => x.PremiumAmount)).Select(x=> new {Count = x.Count(), TotalPremium=x.Sum());